# How to Construct an Object with an Arraylist as Parameter?

Tags: java, arraylist

I want to implement a class for Museum objects.
Each museum Has a name and can contain different Art objects.

Art Objects are implemented within another class
Each Art Object has 3 attributes (name, artist, value)

```
class Pieces_of_art {
    private String name;
    private String artist;
    private float value;

    Pieces_of_art(String name, String artist, float value) {
        this.name = name;
        this.artist = artist;
        this.value = value;
    }
}

class museum {
    Arraylist<Pieces_of_art> set = new ArrayList<>();
    //Initializing Arraylist with type "Piece_of_art" called set and it's empty?
    String name;

    museum(String name, Arraylist<Pieces_of_art> set) {
        this.name = name;
        set = new ArrayList<Piece_of_art>();
    }
}
```

I don't really understand how it is possible to use and arraylist within a constructor as an empty parameter

Comment: what do you mean by `as an empty parameter`?

Comment: sorry I didn't see your comment before. with empty parameter I mean that a museum may contain a list which has no entries yet

Answer (score 0):

There seems no hard to understand. Constructor is a special kind of method. As a method, why not take a List as parameter?

By the way, in your case, you have initialized `set` parameter already. If you want to make use of it. try below

```
museum(String name, Arraylist<Pieces_of_art> set) {
    this.name = name;
    this.set.addAll(set);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me with this syntax, I was not familiar with the "addAll" method
can you tell me how to call this constructor?


          museum Louvre = new museum("Louvre",  ArrayList<Pieces_of_art>set);


this doesn't work for me

Comment: List<Pieces_of_art> arts = new ArrayList<>();
// add some elements
museum Louvre = new museum("Louvre",arts);

Comment: So I have to create a list first in order to pass it to the consctructor. you really helped me  out thanks again :)